# Reinforcement learning for power management

Tags: machine-learning, power-management, reinforcement-learning

I am working on a power management problem where I control the power management of a computing board based on the occurance of events. I am using Reinforcement learning (the traditional Q-learning) for power management where the computing boards works as a Service Provider (SP) for processing requests (images). The SP is connected to a smart camera and the Power Manager (PM) algorithm runs on the camera where it issues appropriate power commands (sleep, wake-up) to the SP. The smart camera captures images (requests) based on the occurance of an event and maintains a Service Queue (SQ) for the requests (images). I also have an ANN based workload estimator that classifies the current workload as *low* or *high*. The state space for the Q-learning algorithm is therefore comprises a composite for Q(s,a) where s=(SR, SQ, SP). SR is the state of the workload. SQ is the state of the service queue and SP is the state of the service provider. 
Based on the current workload, state of the queue and the state of the service provider, the PM issues certain commands to the SP (sleep, wake-up). 
The decision is taken at the following stages:

1. SP is idle
2. SP just entered the sleep state and SQ>=1
3. SP is in the sleep state and SQ transits from 0 to 1.

For each action, a cost is assigned which consists of a weighted sum of average power consumption and average latency per request caused by the action. In both sleep state and idle state, the action comprises selecting some time-out values from a list of pre-defined time-out values.  My problem is as follows:

When the SP enters sleep state and selects a time-out value, some requests may arrive during the time-out value and hence the state of SQ changes. This also changes the composite state (e.g., S(0,0,0) to S(0,N,0). At the end of time-out value, the PM decides to wake-up the SP (as SQ>0). After waking up, the SP processes the requests and when SQ =0 it has a state (0,0,1) or (1,0,1). It then assigns a cost to the previous state. It also updates the Q-matrix accordingly. **My problem is that, shall the cost be assigned to state (0,0,0) or to (0,N,0)?** In principle, the previous state is (0,N,0) but this request is reached automatically at the arrival of some requests in the queue and hence there is not action taken in this state and no action is available to assign cost.

Comment: That's quite a dense post.  Is there any way you can reduce the verbosity, to increase the chance that someone will read it all?

Comment: The problem is that if I don't explain it in detail, it will not make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q-learning applies to Markov Decision Processes (MDP), where performing an action in a given state causes a deterministic transition to a new state.

It is not clear whether the problem you describe is a Partially Observable Markov Decision Process (POMDP) or an MDP. I you have a POMDP (you are making a decision to sleep or wake without information about the state of the queue) then the problem is harder to solve.

If you are only making a sleep-timeout decisions when you can observe the state of the system, then you have an MDP. In this case, you should only update the Q matrix when you reach the next state from which you are selecting an action.

Here is how I understand the sequence of events in your example:

1. The system is sleeping in state (0,0,0)
2. Requests arrive in the queue, the system is still sleeping - (0,N,0).
3. The system wakes up - (0,N,1) or (1,N,1)
4. The system processes the requests - (0|1,0,1)

After step 4, the system needs to make another timeout decision and update the Q matrix. The current state is (0|1,0,1), and this state should be used in the Q-learning algorithm.

You are worried, though, that updating the Q matrix at (0|1,0,1) will not account for the time that the system took to process the N requests that arrived while it was sleeping.
There are probably a number of options to deal with this problem, most of which probably involve restructuring the state space of your problem. One way to do so is to account for the N requests in the reward function - if the system finds a large the number of requests you find on awaking, then it should immediately penalize the previous action.

Comment: You have perfectly understood the problem. The sleep-timeout decisions are based on the observation of the system states. However, I don't know if I can call it an MDP, because the decisions also depend on the past history (workload prediction). I calculate the cost as following. When the system wakes up, it assign a cost to the previous state after processing all the requests. The cost comprises a weighted sum of the immediate average power consumption and the average latency per request. When the system becomes idle, it selects a time-out policy and evaluates this policy in the next state.

Comment: If no request comes during the time-out period, the cost is just average power consumption and the system is shutdown. However, if there are some requests during the transition from idle to sleep, the cost becomes a weighted sum of the average power consumption and the number of requests in the queue (I can't use average latency in this case as the requests are not processed yet). If there comes a request during time-out period, it is immediately processed and the cost is the average power consumption.

Comment: My confusion is that when the system enters the sleep mode and queue is empty, the state is (0|1,0,0). But there may be some requests during the time-out policy and the state changes to (0|1,N,0). When the time-out policy expires, the system wakes up and processes all the requests and assigns cost to the previous state. Shall the state to which the cost is assigned be (0|1,0,0) or (0|1,N,0)? In fact, it is the action in the previous state (time-out values) to which the cost is assigned. But the question is what should be the previous state in which the previous action is assigned the cost?

Comment: The cost should be assigned to (0,0,0) because that is where the system performed its last timeout action.

Comment: You could also potentially perform a timeout action every time you process a request (in this case you would update Q((0|1,N,0),a) ). This configuration would probably make learning less efficient because at the initial stages the system might sleep when the queue was full, but the extra flexibility could lead to greater power efficiency in the later stages.